# What is app:overlayImage in xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto?

Tags: android, xml, namespaces, attributes

I'd like to know what app:overlayImage means and in general, where can I see attribute definitions for the xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto namespace? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you give

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”

all the keys i.e attributes and tags that are attached to this namespace will be imported( or at least sort of ). So next time when you give android: the autocomplete list occurs.